# catkin vs rosbuild system?

Tags: catkin, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
what is the difference between catkin and rosbuild?
In what kind of uses is one of them more preferable than the other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125901/catkin-vs-rosbuild-system?/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbuild` was the buildsystem of ROS since the early times. It uses CMake but invokes it from a Makefiles and builds each package separately and in-source.

`catkin` has been introduced in Groovy (in Fuerte only for testing for some packages). It is using CMake more cleanly and only enhances CMake where that falls short on features. It builds packages out-of-source by default, handles dependencies better and does a much better jobs for packaging. The list of advantages is pretty long and you can find more details here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview

While `rosbuild` can still be used in the future only `catkin` packages can be *released* as of Hydro. So if you can choose you might want to go with `catkin` even if it might take a bit longer to learn the CMake stuff. But whenever you depend on a `rosbuild` package you are forced to stick to `rosbuild`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-04**:
In rosbuild system when i create a package I can't make that in another pc Is catkin same as rosbuild?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: `catkin` is mainly cmake, `rosbuild` uses cmake, but does "stuff" on its own.

The default/preferred build system in ROS is `catkin`. So, you should start new packages in catkin.
However catkin packages can only depend on other catkin packages. So, if you have a dependency that is still on rosbuild, you'll need to convert that first or use rosbuild for your packages.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-04**:
In rosbuild system when i create a package I can't make that in another pc Is catkin same as rosbuild?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-04**:
I don't understand the question. Can you maybe reformulate it?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-04**:
I create one package with rosbuild system in my laptop and then I copy this package in another pc when I try to make that. rosmake can't make that . i can't make my package in another pc with rosbuild.
I have this err"mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/mohammad/ros_workspace/class/build/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/hamid/working_space/class/build where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source "/home/mohammad/ros_workspace/class/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/home/hamid/working_space/class/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory."

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-04**:
You should only copy package sources, not builds. Run make clean before on another machine.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-02-04**:
"make clean" might not be sufficient. Remove the "build" folder.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-02-04**:
Thanks a lot :)